# unable to pass an object as props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

**Objective**: I am trying to pass `selectedFile` (a .png or .jpeg I upload from my computer) as props to my Canvas component (`Canvascompo`). Even though `selectedFile` does render in the current component and has no problem displaying uploaded image, it is undefined when I pass it through as props to `CanvasComponent`.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Canvascompo from "./CanvasComponent"
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardTitle, Breadcrumb, BreadcrumbItem } from 'reactstrap';

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        facesArray: [], // I am able to pass this as props to Canvascompo
        selectedFile: null, //unable to pass through as props to Canvascompo. comes out as undefined
        img: null

    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    // this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

}
```

This is where I try to send objects through as props:
I define `newlist` in my render function.

```
console.log("selected file before update is" , this.state.selectedfile); //undefined
console.log("faces array is ", this.state.facesArray) //works fine
let newlist = this.state.facesArray.map((face, i) => {
    return <Canvascompo faces={face} originalimage={this.state.selectedfile} ivalue={i} key = {i}/>
});
```

**outcome**: faces array returns a filled array(no problem), however, original image is undefined in `Canvascomponent`.

What I have tried so far:

1. I understand that `setState` is asynchronous so I tried to create a callback so that it would set state immediately

   ```
    let url1 = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    // this.setState({selectedFile: url1}, function() {
    //     console.log("inside callback 1", this.state.selectedFile); // returns blob:http://localhost:3000/2be42315-d2b5-4729-b5b0-99c7a84de5ff
    //     this.forceUpdate();

    // });

    this.setState({selectedFile: url1}, function() {
        console.log("did it work 2", this.state.selectedFile); // returns blob:http://localhost:3000/2be42315-d2b5-4729-b5b0-99c7a84de5ff


        <Canvascompo originalimage={this.state.selectedfile} />
    });
    console.log("selected File after callback is", this.state.selectedFile) // null
   ```
2. Inside my fetch API, I use a promise to `setState` my `facesArray`(which works) so I decided to do the same for `selectedFile`

   ```
    .then((response) => response.json()).then(success => {
    that.setState({selectedFile: url1});

            that.setState({facesArray: success});
            console.log("facesArray is", that.state.facesArray);
            console.log("new selected state is", that.state.selectedFile); // blob:http://localhost:3000/2be42315-d2b5-4729-b5b0-99c7a84de5ff
            // console.log(success);
        }).catch(error =>
            console.log("did not work ",error))
    };
   ```
3. Used `ComponentDidUpdate` to check that `selectedFile` actually updates(it does).

   ```
    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log("selected file in CDU is ", this.state.selectedFile); //blob:http://localhost:3000/2be42315-d2b5-4729-b5b0-99c7a84de5ff
    }
   ```

Final notes:
My idea is that on these two lines before I create `newlist`

```
    console.log("selected file before update is" , this.state.selectedfile); //undefined
    console.log("faces array is ", this.state.facesArray) //works fine
    let newlist = this.state.facesArray.map((face, i) => {
        return <Canvascompo faces={face} originalimage={this.state.selectedfile} ivalue={i} key ={i}/>
    });
```

I need `selectedFile` to properly print its result. This is why I have been trying to immediately `setState` `selectedFile`, and although it works in the callback, it does not permanently `setState` afterwards because it is still undefined.

Comment: your state variable is initialised as `selectedFile` but you are passing `originalimage={this.state.selectedfile}` - note the different case of the `f` of "file"

Comment: Thank you so much!